# How can i get the sheet order as per required irrespective of the sheet order in excel

Tags: c#, excel, .net-2.0

My `excel` file consists of the following `sheets`

```
|_____|_____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____||____||____||____||____|
|_____|_____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____||____||____||____||____|
|_____|_____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____||____||____||____||____|
\__Basic Salary__/\__Bank__/\__Contact__/\__Hourly Salary__/\__Presonal__/
```

Some thing like this what ever order of the `sheets` i would like to arrange them in my required order as follows

```
1) Personal
2) Contact
3) Salary
4) Bank
```

In this order I would like to get irrespective of the sheet names that I get I would like to arrange in the order I required.

Comment: what has this got to do with asp? or, for that matter, .NET? is this using VSTO? or...?

Comment: I am using `Visual studio` only. I would like to get as per the order i required later on i have to do the required code. At present i am storing `Sheet names` in `string[]` but not as per my required order as per asked

Comment: How are you actually generating the sheets though - 3rd party control maybe? Xml?

Comment: I said that it is an `Excel` file..

Comment: @User a file is just a sequence of bytes; you are presumably using some API to *look at/manipulate the contents* of the file....?

Comment: Please avoid the `asp` tag in the future. Use either `asp.net` or `asp-classic` instead.

Comment: Also, even if it's for an asp.net page, this question really has nothing to do with asp.net anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, then your book's `.Worksheets` has methods such as `Move([before], [after])`. As such, I would suggest playing with [the `Move()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.move.aspx) to re-order the sheets. Note (from the tags): you should not use excel automation from a web application; that scenario is not supported.